# D3.js Tree View collapse not working in my application

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, kendo-ui

I added a d3.js library to project and i have few other libraries like jQuery, kendo ui, jQuery ui etc.

but collapse is not working on click of node of tree view. It is working in js fiddle but not in my application. is there are any conflicts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
stroke: steelblue;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #ccc;
 stroke-width: 1.5px;
 }

 </style>
 <body>
 <div id="lineageTrack"></div>
 <script src="d3.js"></script>
 <script>

   var margin = {
          top: 20,
          right: 120,
          bottom: 20,
          left: 120
      },
      width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
      height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var root = {
          "name": "flare",
              "children": [{
              "name": "analytics"
              }, {
                  "name": "graph"
              }]

              };

      var i = 0,
          duration = 750,
          rectW = 60,
          rectH = 30;

      var tree = d3.layout.tree().nodeSize([70, 40]);
      var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
          .projection(function (d) {
          return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2];
      });

      var svg = d3.select("#lineageTrack").append("svg").attr("width", 1000).attr("height", 1000)
          .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1,3]).on("zoom", redraw)).append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + 350 + "," + 20 + ")");

      //necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
      zm.translate([350, 20]);

      root.x0 = 0;
      root.y0 = height / 2;

      function collapse(d) {
          if (d.children) {
              d._children = d.children;
              d._children.forEach(collapse);
              d.children = null;
          }
      }

      root.children.forEach(collapse);
      update(root);

      d3.select("#lineageTrack").style("height", "800px");

      function update(source) {

          // Compute the new tree layout.
          var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
              links = tree.links(nodes);

          // Normalize for fixed-depth.
          nodes.forEach(function (d) {
              d.y = d.depth * 180;
          });

          // Update the nodes…
          var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
              .data(nodes, function (d) {
              return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
          });

          // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
          var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("transform", function (d) {
              return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
          })
              .on("click", click);

          nodeEnter.append("rect")
              .attr("width", rectW)
              .attr("height", rectH)
              .attr("stroke", "black")
              .attr("stroke-width", 1)
              .style("fill", function (d) {
              return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
          });

          nodeEnter.append("text")
              .attr("x", rectW / 2)
              .attr("y", rectH / 2)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
              .text(function (d) {
              return d.name;
          });

          // Transition nodes to their new position.
          var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("transform", function (d) {
              return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });

          nodeUpdate.select("rect")
              .attr("width", rectW)
              .attr("height", rectH)
              .attr("stroke", "black")
              .attr("stroke-width", 1)
              .style("fill", function (d) {
              return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
          });

          nodeUpdate.select("text")
              .style("fill-opacity", 1);

          // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
          var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("transform", function (d) {
              return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
          })
              .remove();

          nodeExit.select("rect")
              .attr("width", rectW)
              .attr("height", rectH)
          //.attr("width", bbox.getBBox().width)""
          //.attr("height", bbox.getBBox().height)
          .attr("stroke", "black")
              .attr("stroke-width", 1);

          nodeExit.select("text");

          // Update the links…
          var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
              .data(links, function (d) {
              return d.target.id;
          });

          // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
          link.enter().insert("path", "g")
              .attr("class", "link")
              .attr("x", rectW / 2)
              .attr("y", rectH / 2)
              .attr("d", function (d) {
              var o = {
                  x: source.x0,
                  y: source.y0
              };
              return diagonal({
                  source: o,
                  target: o
              });
          });

          // Transition links to their new position.
          link.transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("d", diagonal);

          // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
          link.exit().transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .attr("d", function (d) {
              var o = {
                  x: source.x,
                  y: source.y
              };
              return diagonal({
                  source: o,
                  target: o
              });
          })
              .remove();

          // Stash the old positions for transition.
          nodes.forEach(function (d) {
              d.x0 = d.x;
              d.y0 = d.y;
          });
      }

      // Toggle children on click.
      function click(d) {
          if (d.children) {
              d._children = d.children;
              d.children = null;
          } else {
              d.children = d._children;
              d._children = null;
          }
          update(d);
      }

      //Redraw for zoom
      function redraw() {
        //console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
        svg.attr("transform",
            "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")"
            + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
      }

     </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

[see the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzxm2.png)

Comment: can we see the fiddle?

Comment: Nevermind, got it: https://plnkr.co/edit/FMPWuwf7RHJCxc37xRaq?p=preview. Does your console display an error? is `<script src="d3.js"></script>` a legit path?

Comment: Thanks echonax.

No.
console not showing any errors.

Comment: when i click to collapse on node it doesnt collapse and when i click again to expand it will add one more <g> path and doesnt remove the older ones

so, it increases with clicks

Comment: And the code is exactly the same with above?

Comment: yes.
except i have not attached any other libraries.

Comment: It's worked on my local server as it. Looks like a conflict with other libraries. Comment all others and then uncomment one by one until you get the responsable

Comment: ok. let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file may conflict with `jquery.min.js` or with other libraries and so that it may be in conflict. So you need to keep the `d3.js` file just above to all library files. It will work fine.

Comment: Thanks Anand.

it worked fine.

i kept d3.js library source before loading all libraries.
thanks for your answer.